# Background image don't work on last <td>

Tags: html, css

I have applied background image for `<td>`. What my actual problem is that I can see the image in only first 2 `<td>`'s on third `<td>` the image is not being displayed. Help me out.

```html
<tr style="background: white url(&quot;image.jpg&quot;) no-repeat;background-size: 45% 100%;background-position: 98% 0%;">
   <td style="padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;" valign="top">
      <img src="image.png" width="100">
   </td>
   <td width="220">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
   <td width="220">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Table elements don't tend to play nice with background images.

Comment: but it work on first 2 td and if i put red color on background it work on all td's but image won't work!

Comment: check your code and link the images properly.

Comment: thank you all just find a solution!!! create <table> for this <tr> and  put backgournd to <table> inline style! and it work fine!